# How to train model with features selected by SelectKBest?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-selection

I am using `SelectKBest()` in Sklearn's `Pipeline()` class to reduce the number of features down from 30 to the 5 best features. When I fit the classifer, I get different test results as expected with feature selection. However I spotted an error in my code which doesn't seem to cause an actual error in runtime.

When I call `predict()`, I realised that it was still being given all 30 features as input as if feature selection wasn't occurring. Even though I only trained the model on the 5 best features. Surely giving 30 features to an SVM to predict a class will crash if it was only trained on the 5 best features?

In my `train_model(df)` function, my code looks as follows:

```py
def train_model(df):
    x,y = balance_dataset(df)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)

    feature_selection = SelectKBest()

    pipe = Pipeline([('sc', preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()),
                    ('feature_selection', feature_selection),
                    ('SVM', svm.SVC(decision_function_shape = 'ovr', kernel = 'poly'))])

    candidate_parameters = [{'SVM__C': [0.01, 0.1, 1], 'SVM__gamma': [0.01, 0.1, 1], 'feature_selection__k': [5]}]

    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid = candidate_parameters, cv = 5, n_jobs = -1)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train )

    return clf
```

However this is when what happens when I call `trade()`:

```py
def trade(df):
    clf = train_model(df) 

    for index, row in trading_set.iterrows(): 

        features = row[:-3] #features is now an array of 30 features, even though model is only trained on 5

        if trade_balance > 0:
            trades[index] = trade_balance
            if clf.predict(features) == 1: #So this should crash and give an input Shape error, but it doesn't
            #Rest of code unneccesary#
```

So my question is, how do I know that the model is really being trained on only the 5 best features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, and there is no reason why it should throw you any error. You are confused between the pipeline object and the model itself, which is only one block of the pipeline.

In your example, the pipeline is taking 30 features, scaling them, selecting the 5 best, then training an SVM on these 5 best features. So your SVM has been trained on 5 best features, but you still need to pass all 30 features to your pipeline, because your pipeline expects data to come in in the same format as during the training.

Comment: Wow that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you for clearing that up for me, as I was really confused as to how it was still working. Can I now ask, are the stages that I have outlined in the pipeline done in the correct order? As I have balanced the dataset using random up sampling, I then scale and select best features and do GridSearch with CV. I'm just concerned about _Data leakage_ and ensuring the order flow of stages are correct. Or does this ultimately come down to the 'no free lunch theorem'?

Comment: Your pipeline makes total sense to me. And I don't see any data leakage in your setting :)

Comment: Even if my `balance_dataset()` method randomly upsamples data from the entire train set? so duplicate data could be distributed between folds in the cv process?

Comment: Indeed, you are right about the upsampling, I had not paid attention. You actually have two solutions to avoid this: undersampling (but this might lead to substantial data loss if the imbalance is significant) or adding the data resampling in the pipeline itself (see https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)

Comment: Interesting, I've just a read over their docs. I feel a bit queasy about connecting the two libraries `imblearn` and `sklearn` just together like that. Is this a common solution for dealing with these sort of problems? Apologies if this comment appears too opinionated.

Comment: All I can tell you is that I've done it before and it is usually considered a common practice. `sklearn` does not have any resampling options, and this is something you will need to do using `imblearn`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help! I'll mark your answer as the best answer!